# divs not properly aligned side by side

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have 3 divs placed side by side in my application , and after the divs , I have kept a submit button.

This is how the **Submit** button looks if I select 'today' in date options :

[image]

but if I choose specific dates , this is what happens :

[image]
This is how the code looks like :

```
<div class="filters clearfix" style="float:left" id="sel_filters">
    <div class="fields">
       <div class="10">
          <!-- this is for the date option . it contains a label and select element-->
       </div>
       <div>
          <!-- label for start date and an input box -->
       </div>
       <div>
          <!-- label for end date and an input box -->
       </div>
       <div>
          <!-- label for adnetwork options "&nbsp;" and the select element -->
       </div>
       <input id="startdate_hidden" type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="" name="data[Fam][startdate_hidden]">
        <input id="enddate_hidden" type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="" name="data[Fam][enddate_hidden]">
        <input id="submit" class="stdButton" type="submit" onclick="return  updateAddetailsNetworkWiseReport();" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the styles :

```
.clearfix:after 
{
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
div#sel_filters 
{
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 754px;
}

div.filters div.fields 
{
  background: url("/img/bg_summary.gif") no-repeat scroll right bottom #FFFFFF;
  height: 38px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
div#sel_filters div.fields div.l0 
{
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

I added **style="float:left"** to the outermost div , but this problem persists . What's the exact solution would be?

Comment: With specific dates, the total width of all the inner elements is longer since the two date picker icons are now visible. The natural layout of the document cannot fit all the elements in the given space so it moves the last element (the submit button) down to the next row. You could try removing any unwanted margins or padding from the elements or making `#sel_filters` wider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like on the bottom image two images are appearing next to the date boxes and this is causing the elements to be to wide for the containing div.

Try resizing some of the elements to make them smaller by 20-30px or; make the containing divisions width bigger, this should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

instead `float` you can use `display:inline-block` for this with `white-space` property. Like this:

**CSS:**

```
.parent{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.child{
    background:red;
    margin:10px;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    white-space:normal;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline /*IE7*/
    *zoom:1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/amhWX/